# Gradle dependency resolve Issue with profile

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have build a maven project A inside that build.xml include all test dependencies import using another pom.
when I trying to include that maven project A to gradle project B 
It gives error.

I try with [--info] first it tries correct repository url and updating jar [Cached resource is up-to-date]. But finally it tries others and throws error.

How to pass profile name form gradle build file?

helps are appreciated.

Project A -> Maven Build - pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.spring.test</groupId>
<artifactId>Rest</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Project</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <JUnitBOM.version.number>1.0.0</JUnitBOM.version.number>        
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>JUnitBOM</artifactId>
            <version>${JUnitBOM.version.number}-${project.qualifier}
           </version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <profile>
        <id>AUAT</id>
        <properties>
            <env>uat</env>              
            <project.qualifier>SNAPSHOT</project.qualifier>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
```

Project B -> gradle build - build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = "com.spring.integration" 
status = 'integration' 
version = '1.0.0' 
sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {   
  maven { url "http://repo1" }  
  maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/release" }   
  maven { url "http://maven.restlet.org" } }

dependencies {   
  compile group:'com.spring.test', name:'Rest', version:'1.0.0-SNAPSHOT', classifier: 'AUAT'    
  compile group:'org.restlet.jee', name:'org.restlet', version:'2.2'   
  compile group:'org.restlet.jee', name:'org.restlet.ext.servlet',version:'1.1'   
  compile group:'org.springframework', name:'spring-web',    version:'3.2.1.RELEASE'   
  compile group:'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.2'   
  compile group:'ch.qos.logback', name:'logback-core', version:'1.0.9'   
  testCompile group:'junit', name:'junit', version:'4.11' 

}
```

Error Message

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve com.spring.test:Rest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
  com.spring.test:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
> Could not resolve com.test:JUnitBOM:1.0.0-${project.qualifier}.
  > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
  > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
  > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
> Could not HEAD 'http://maven.restlet.org/com/spring/test/Rest/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Rest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict
```

Comment: The Property project.qualifier seems to be undefined.

Comment: `compile group:'com.spring.test', name:'Rest', version:'1.0.0-SNAPSHOT', classifier: 'AUAT'`
means `com.spring.test:Rest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:AUAT`, I did not see how it got connected to your `profile` in POM.xml

Comment: com.spring.test:Rest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:AUAT ->  is it  not work as profile = AUAT? how can i solve this?

Comment: why profile is undefined i generating first jar classifier from {project.qualifier}.

Comment: `AUAT` is classfier not profile.qualifier, like jar or war

Comment: how can i pass qualifier from gradle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Gradle maven settings plugin https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.linguica.maven-settings.
With the maven settings plugin, you can pass the activeProfiles, custom maven settings file.